# Excel formula in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I would like to use the following excel (table) function in Power Query:

```
{=IF([@[Month_N]]=MIN(IF([Pers_ID]=[@[Pers_ID]];[Month_N]));TRUE;FALSE)}
```

It gives me for a distinct `Pers_ID` with the lowest `Month_N` number a `TRUE` and otherwise a `FALSE`.

Is there a way to do this in Power Query?

Reason: I would like to automate different steps in Excel via power query so I can start analyzing my data right away.

Comment: It would help if you show an example of your data and desired output. Take a look at the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is added to Power Query as `Table1`:

1. `Duplicate` the `Table1` query, renaming this new query as `Table2`
2. Add a step to the `Table2` query in which you use the `Group By` feature, grouping on `Pers_ID`, with *New column name*=`MinMonth`, *Operation*=`Min`and *Column*=`Month_N`
3. Back in the `Table1` query, `Merge Queries` (**not** `as New`) on `Table 1` and `Table2`, choosing the `Pers_ID` column from both, `Left Outer` join.
4. `Expand` the `Table2` column after this merge, selecting the `MinMonth` column only
5. Add a simple `Calculated Column` to check if the entry in the `MinMonth` column is equal to that in the `Month_N` column
6. `Delete` unwanted columns as required